# How do I apply unknown arguments to a function in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, function, arguments, apply

I'm developing my own GUI for my [engine](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame), and I've created an "object" called EwConsole (A simple "drop-down" console to input commands). In order to do that, I simply store an ID for the function to be "triggered with enter/return" as the key to the function-object itself in a dict. My problem is with the arguments, and Python 3.x.

Here's my method for creating a new "console command":

```
def create_command(self, command_id, command_function):
    self["commands"][command_id] = command_function
```

I've developed my own input object, called "EwInput", which has a method that returns the string value that has been written in it. In order to separate the arguments of the stored command, I split the spaces of the string. Here's the code that "watches" for "commands" in the console:

```
def watch_for_commands(self):
    if push_enter():
        values = self["input"].get_value().split()
        if values[0] in self["commands"]:
            if len(values) == 1:
                self["commands"][values[0]]()
            elif len(values) > 1:
                try:
                    self["commands"][values[0]](values[1:]) # Problem here.
                except TypeError:
                    raise ErgameError("The given function '{0}' does not support the given arguments: {1}.".format(values[0], values[1:]))
        else:
            print("There is no such command: {}".format(values[0]))
```

As you can see, since the "command creation" is completely generic, it's not possible to know how many arguments the given function will have. [As one can see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), in the old 2.x, it was possible to use "apply" with a list of arguments.

Now comes the question:

How, in Python 3.x, can I "apply" an unknown number of arguments to a function, if it is forcing me to use "__ call __"??? Is there a way in Python 3.x to apply an arbitrary SEQUENCE of arguments to an unknown function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
self["commands"][values[0]](*values[1:])
```

Comment: huahuahuau.. Brilliant! Much better than apply, and I had no idea of it. Thank you very much!