# NameError: name 'apply' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

When I run the code below , I receive an error `NameError: name 'apply' is not defined`. Why is this happening?

```
from tkinter import *

movieList = ["1 Frozen 06/15 11:35 95", "3 Frozen 06/18 11:35 95",
        "4 Frozen 06/30 11:25 95", "5 Frozen 07/02 11:45 95",
        "6 Frozen 07/05 12:30 95"]

master = Tk()

option = StringVar(master)
option.set(movieList[0]) # Set the first value to be the default option

w = apply(OptionMenu, (master, option) + tuple(movieList))
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031725/how-do-i-apply-unknown-arguments-to-a-function-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 8):

[What's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> Instead of `apply(f, args)` use `f(*args)`.

Replace this:

```
w = apply(OptionMenu, (master, option) + tuple(movieList))
```

with this:

```
w = OptionMenu(*(master, option) + tuple(movieList))
```